# Reading text file into array character by character, maybe with vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a text file that is in the format of a rectangle, with various characters. What I want to do is to read that text file into a 2d array, like a grid. For an example, if the text file was something like this

```
15681
28515
32414
12451
```

If I was to call grid[3][2], with [x] and [y] parameters respectively, the value of grid[3][2] would be 5, which is found in row 3, column 2.

I originally tried doing this by declaring the grid as a char array

```
array[x][y]
```

Where I had determined the values of x and y (how many lines were in the file, how many columns were in the file) by reading how many lines were in the file, and how many characters were in a line. I know that my code is likely superfluous and I could cut down on the amount of work by implementing a vector array, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

```
int x = 0; int y = 0;
grid[x][y] = whatever the current character in the file is;
every time a character is stored, x++
when a newline is encountered, y++;
```

I would think that would properly save all the values to the grid, but I don't know the syntax on how to do that.

Another idea I thought about was to maybe have an array of Points, a class I would create that would contain an X value and a Y value, though I've no idea how I would actually implement it.

I've got no idea about how to go about doing the first option syntax wise, and I've got no clue on how to even start with my second option. Can anyone give me some hints or redirect me to any information that would help teach me?

EDIT:
code that crashes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
std::vector<std::string> grid;
std::string line;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
std::string current_exec_name = argv[0];
std::string filename;
if (argc > 1){
    filename = argv[1];
}
cout << filename;
ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
while (infile.good())
{
    grid.push_back(line);
}
grid[2][1] = 4;
//the line above

}
```

I've tried doing the following codes where the program crashes

```
grid[2][1] = 4;
grid[2][1] = "4";
grid[2] = 4;
grid[2] = "4";
```

The program builds, but crashes when it runs.

Comment: `grid[3][2]` should actually return 4 (assuming we start counting the indices from 0). Right?

Comment: Yeah, I just forgot to include 0. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a vector of strings to insert each line into:

```
std::vector<std::string> grid;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(in, line))
{
    grid.push_back(line);
}
```

Now by accessing the `[x][y]` points you will get the correct character in the file:

```
grid[3][2]; // 4
```

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to as a test, (after implementing the above code), declare that grid[3][2] = 4, and then cout grid[3][4], but the program crashes. It builds right, but it crashes. Was I supposed to do a different declaration of grid, the first line in the code you gave me?

Comment: @JoJoBya Can you show me your actual code that crashes? Maybe I can help.

Comment: @JoJoBya I think I see the problem. You're doing `while (infile.good())` when you should be doing `while (std::getline(infile, line))`. Sorry I took so long to reply, I had to help my mom with something.

Comment: Well, replacing while (infile.good()) with while (std::getline(infile, line)) makes it give me an error of "no matching function for call to 'getline'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41834/discussion-between-jojo-bya-and-0x499602d2)

Comment: @JoJoBya You did `getline(line)` when it should be `getline(infile, line)`.